# How to make Wordpress category IDs sequential?

Tags: wordpress

I've noticed when I create a new category in one of my Wordpress 2.9.2 installations that the new category ID isn't sequential.

I have created five categories and the id's so far are: 15, 23, 34, 36, and now the newest one, 54.

This isn't really a problem, but is kind of annoying! And I haven't seen it before on other installations.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why this is, but are you rewriting your URLs in the front-end? Your visitors shouldn't be seeing the IDs at all then.

Comment: Thanks Pekka - you're right the URLs aren't visible, I'd just like to address the problem more for coding consistency.

Answer (score 0):

The IDs are based on [MySQL auto-incremental indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-auto-increment-handling.html).

Did you add or delete tags, custom terms or other categories in-between adding the ones you've mentioned?

Comment: Thanks! I'll look closer into this.